# Is there a possibility to filter duplicate items by a field using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a possibility to filter duplicate items by a field using Lodash?

I have an array with several items, some of these items are duplicated, what differentiates is the validade field that is different.

Is it possible to filter and keep only one item?

Note: Null items must remain

```
[
  {
    "oa": 1,
    "id": 168,
    "lote": "2022-05-31-1672012800",
    "tipo_estoque": "MP",
    "data_entrada": "2022-07-11 10:25:25.0",
    "produto_id": 1,
    "item_id": 2594,
    "created_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "validade": "2023-05-11 00:00:00.0",
    "siaId": "02.352"
  },
  {
    "oa": 1,
    "id": 228,
    "lote": "2022-05-31-1672012801",
    "tipo_estoque": "MP",
    "data_entrada": "2022-07-11 10:25:25.0",
    "produto_id": 1,
    "item_id": 2594,
    "created_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "validade": "2023-06-11 00:00:00.0",
    "siaId": "02.352"
  },
  {
    "oa": 2,
    "id": null,
    "lote": null,
    "tipo_estoque": null,
    "data_entrada": null,
    "produto_id": null,
    "item_id": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "validade": null,
    "siaId": null
  },
  {
    "oa": 3,
    "id": 168,
    "lote": "2022-05-31-1672012800",
    "tipo_estoque": "MP",
    "data_entrada": "2022-07-11 10:25:25.0",
    "produto_id": 1,
    "item_id": 2594,
    "created_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "validade": "2023-05-11 00:00:00.0",
    "siaId": "02.352"
  },
  {
    "oa": 3,
    "id": 228,
    "lote": "2022-05-31-1672012801",
    "tipo_estoque": "MP",
    "data_entrada": "2022-07-11 10:25:25.0",
    "produto_id": 1,
    "item_id": 2594,
    "created_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "validade": "2023-06-11 00:00:00.0",
    "siaId": "02.352"
  },
  {
    "oa": 4,
    "id": null,
    "lote": null,
    "tipo_estoque": null,
    "data_entrada": null,
    "produto_id": null,
    "item_id": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "validade": null,
    "siaId": null
  },
  {
    "oa": 5,
    "id": null,
    "lote": null,
    "tipo_estoque": null,
    "data_entrada": null,
    "produto_id": null,
    "item_id": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "validade": null,
    "siaId": null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) but it doesn't deal with the "`null` items must remain" criteria, here's an example:

```js
const items = [/* your items, as described in the question */]
const uniques = _.uniqBy(items, (item) => item.validade)
```

If order doesn't matter then you could do it with a combo of [partition](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#partition) and [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy):

```js
const items = [/* your items, as described in the question */]
const [withNullDate, withNonNullDate] = _.partition(items, (item) => item.validade === null)
const uniquesWithNonNullDate = _.uniqBy(withNonNullDate, (item) => item.validade)
const uniquesAndNulls = [...uniquesWithNonNullDate, ...withNullDate]
```

Answer (score 0):

We group by the `validade` property (using Array.reduce method) only we don't care about it just push whatever is not duplicate into the `result` array.

```js
var arr = [{
    "oa": 1,
    "id": 168,
    "lote": "2022-05-31-1672012800",
    "tipo_estoque": "MP",
    "data_entrada": "2022-07-11 10:25:25.0",
    "produto_id": 1,
    "item_id": 2594,
    "created_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "validade": "2023-05-11 00:00:00.0",
    "siaId": "02.352"
  },
  {
    "oa": 1,
    "id": 228,
    "lote": "2022-05-31-1672012801",
    "tipo_estoque": "MP",
    "data_entrada": "2022-07-11 10:25:25.0",
    "produto_id": 1,
    "item_id": 2594,
    "created_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "validade": "2023-06-11 00:00:00.0",
    "siaId": "02.352"
  },
  {
    "oa": 2,
    "id": null,
    "lote": null,
    "tipo_estoque": null,
    "data_entrada": null,
    "produto_id": null,
    "item_id": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "validade": null,
    "siaId": null
  },
  {
    "oa": 3,
    "id": 168,
    "lote": "2022-05-31-1672012800",
    "tipo_estoque": "MP",
    "data_entrada": "2022-07-11 10:25:25.0",
    "produto_id": 1,
    "item_id": 2594,
    "created_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "validade": "2023-05-11 00:00:00.0",
    "siaId": "02.352"
  },
  {
    "oa": 3,
    "id": 228,
    "lote": "2022-05-31-1672012801",
    "tipo_estoque": "MP",
    "data_entrada": "2022-07-11 10:25:25.0",
    "produto_id": 1,
    "item_id": 2594,
    "created_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-11 13:25:32.0",
    "validade": "2023-06-11 00:00:00.0",
    "siaId": "02.352"
  },
  {
    "oa": 4,
    "id": null,
    "lote": null,
    "tipo_estoque": null,
    "data_entrada": null,
    "produto_id": null,
    "item_id": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "validade": null,
    "siaId": null
  },
  {
    "oa": 5,
    "id": null,
    "lote": null,
    "tipo_estoque": null,
    "data_entrada": null,
    "produto_id": null,
    "item_id": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "validade": null,
    "siaId": null
  }
]


var result = [];
arr.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  if (item.validade === null) {
    result.push(item)
  } else {

    if (!agg[item.validade]) {
      result.push(item)
      agg[item.validade] = true;
    } 
  }
  return agg;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important }
```